# Вернуть результат выборки из БД.

Tags: база-данных, java

Объясните, пожалуйста, в каком виде вернуть данные из функции, которая достает данные из БД. Есть функция `getData()`, в ней `result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");`.
А в каком виде возвращать данные через `return`? Объект `SetResult`, наверное, не стоит возвращать. И главное, как потом вывести эти данные, например, через таблицу, подставляя нужные поля в нужные места при выводе? В Сети ничего такого не могу найти, сам уже и так и сяк пробовал, не получается.

Comment: Как так не нашли, мало кто это не умеет:

[mkyong][1]
[jenkov][2]


  [1]: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-select-list-of-the-records/
  [2]: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html#iterating-the-resultset

Comment: бывал я на этих сайтах. Но там не совсем то, что мне нужно. Мне нужно вернуть результат из метода, в данных вами примерах такого нет. Вернуть надо, что типа ключ - значение. Потом это дело в цикле вывести в окне программы

Comment: @sew810i9_I9 Eсли ты выбираеш все столбы(*) то какой ещё "ключ-значение" ? В тех гайдах всё лаконично и просто. Этим пользуются ВСЕ и нет проблем у кого либо. У тебя чтото не так. Лучше покажи свой код

Comment: argamidon, http://pastebin.com/zmxbGKTa

Answer (score 1):

Создай класс-сущность, т.е. в данном случае User.
Создай список, типизированный этим классом, - `List<User> list=new ArrayList<>();`

```
while (result.next()) {
           тут создаёшь User объект и пихаеш его в список
           User user=new User ();
           user.setName(result.getString("name_column"));
           list.add(user);
}
```

А после опроса БД отправляешь этот список куда хочешь.

Comment: argamidon, так http://pastebin.com/Ry19BAQx ?

Comment: да. так. только метод `public List<User> getData()` должнн быть не у User. User должен только хранить инфу о юзере. он не должен знать о БД вообще

Comment: argamidon, что-то я я не понял эту строчку - "метод public List<User> getData() должен быть не у User". У меня в классе User нет такого метода, может ты что-то не так написал?

Comment: я ошибся. да. у тебя всё нормально.